# Using LINQ with stored procedure that returns multiple instances of the same entity per row

Tags: linq, stored-procedures

Our development policy dictates that all database accesses are made via stored procedures, and this is creating an issue when using LINQ.

The scenario discussed below has been somewhat simplified, in order to make the explanation easier.

Consider a database that has 2 tables.

- Orders (OrderID (PK), InvoiceAddressID (FK), DeliveryAddressID (FK) )
- Addresses (AddresID (PK), Street, ZipCode)

The resultset returned by the stored procedure has to rename the address related columns, so that the invoice and delivery addresses are distinct from each other.

```
OrderID InvAddrID DelAddrID InvStreet DelStreet InvZipCode DelZipCode
1       27        46        Main St   Back St   abc123     xyz789
```

This, however, means that LINQ has no idea what to do with these columns in the resultset, as they no longer match the property names in the Address entity.

The frustrating thing about this is that there seems to be no way to define which resultset columns map to which Entity properties, even though it is possible (to a certain extent) to map entity properties to stored procedure parameters for the insert/update operations.

Has anybody else had the same issue?

I'd imagine that this would be a relatively common scenarios, from a schema point of view, but the stored procedure seems to be the key factor here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered creating a view like the below for the stored procedure to select from? It would add complexity, but allow LINQ to see the Entity the way you wanted.

```
Create view OrderAddress as 
Select o.OrderID 
,i.AddressID as InvID
,d.AddressID as DelID
...
from Orders o
left join Addresses  i
on o.InvAddressID= i.AddressID
left join Addresses d
on o.DelAddressID = i.AddressID
```

Comment: Won't that simply obtain the same resultset (and column names) as the stored procedure?
This issue that I'm having problems with is getting LINQ to understand the mapping between resultset columns and entity properties.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is a bit fussy about querying data; it wants the schema to match. I suspect you're going to have to bring that back into an automatically generated type, and do the mapping to you entity type afterwards **in LINQ to objects** (i.e. after AsEnumerable() or similar) - as it doesn't like you creating instances of the mapped entities manually inside a query.

Actually, I would recommend challenging the requirement in one respect: rather than SPs, consider using UDFs to query data; they work similarly in terms of being owned by the database, but they are composable at the server (paging, sorting, joinable, etc).

(this bit a bit random - take with a pinch of salt)

UDFs can be associated with entity types if the schema matches, so another option (I haven't tried it) would be to have a GetAddress(id) udf, and a "main" udf, and join them:

```
var qry = from row in ctx.MainUdf(id)
          select new {
             Order = ctx.GetOrder(row.OrderId),
             InvoiceAddress = ctx.GetAddress(row.InvoiceAddressId),
             DeliveryAddress = ctx.GetAddress(row.DeliveryAddressId)) };
```

(where the udf just returns the ids - actually, you might have the **join** to the other udfs, making it even worse).

or something - might be too messy for serious consideration, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you know exactly what columns your result set will include, you should be able to create a new entity type that has properties for each column in the result set.  Rather than trying to pack the data into an `Order`, for example, you can pack it into an `OrderWithAddresses`, which has exactly the structure your stored procedure would expect.  If you're using LINQ to Entities, you should even be able to indicate in your .edmx file that an OrderWithAddresses is an Order with two additional properties.  In LINQ to SQL you will have to specify all of the columns as if it were an entirely unrelated data type.

If your columns get generated dynamically by the stored procedure, you will need to try a different approach:  Create a new stored procedure that only pulls data from the Orders table, and one that only pulls data from the addresses table.  Set up your LINQ mapping to use these stored procedures instead.  (Of course, the only reason you're using stored procs is to comply with your company policy).  Then, use LINQ to join these data.  It should be only slightly less efficient, but it will more appropriately reflect the actual structure of your data, which I think is better programming practice.

Comment: Interesting ideas - I will try the first suggestion as soon as I can, but it smells a bit of 'Adapting the code to the technology'.

Looks like I need to investigate LINQ to Entities as an alternative technology.

Need to organise (and justify) some research time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're after, but I could wildy off...

If you mock up classes in a DBML (right-click -> new -> class) that are the same structure as your source tables, you could simply create new objects based on what is read from the stored procedure.  Using LINQ to objects, you could still query your selection.  It's more code, but it's not that hard to do.  For example, mock up your DBML like this:

[Pay attention to the associations http://geeksharp.com/screens/orders-dbml.png](http://geeksharp.com/screens/orders-dbml.png)

Make sure you pay attention to the associations I added.  You can expand "Parent Property" and change the name of those associations to "InvoiceAddress" and "DeliveryAddress."  I also changed the child property names to "InvoiceOrders" and "DeliveryOrders" respectively.  Notice the stored procedure up top called "usp_GetOrders."  Now, with a bit of code, you can map the columns manually.  I know it's not ideal, especially if the stored proc doesn't expose every member of each table, but it can get you close:

```
public List<Order> GetOrders()
{
    // our DBML classes
    List<Order> dbOrders = new List<Order>();

    using (OrderSystemDataContext db = new OrderSystemDataContext())
    {
        // call stored proc
        var spOrders = db.usp_GetOrders();

        foreach (var spOrder in spOrders)
        {
            Order ord = new Order();
            Address invAddr = new Address();
            Address delAddr = new Address();

            // set all the properties
            ord.OrderID = spOrder.OrderID;

            // add the invoice address
            invAddr.AddressID = spOrder.InvAddrID;
            invAddr.Street = spOrder.InvStreet;
            invAddr.ZipCode = spOrder.InvZipCode;
            ord.InvoiceAddress = invAddr;

            // add the delivery address
            delAddr.AddressID = spOrder.DelAddrID;
            delAddr.Street = spOrder.DelStreet;
            delAddr.ZipCode = spOrder.DelZipCode;
            ord.DeliveryAddress = delAddr;

            // add to the collection
            dbOrders.Add(ord);
        }
    }

    // at this point I have a List of orders I can query...
    return dbOrders;
}
```

Again, I realize this seems cumbersome, but I think the end result is worth a few extra lines of code.

Comment: This seems to make the most sense of the answers given so far.
I'm busy on a 54 mile charity bike ride tomorrow, but will be at home on Monday (recovering), so intend to use the opportunity to put together a proof of concept project.

Comment: Having done some more work with LINQ (Without stored procedures) I have a bit better understanding of how things work. The issue that I now have, with the above method, is I've lost the mapping that LINQ provides, and every query that does soemthing with an order has to jump through the same kind of hoops. Sure, the guts of this code can be factored out to a separate method, but that still leaves me composing objects al over the place instead of leaving LINQ to do the heavy lifting (As it was designed to do)
Food for thought though.

Answer (score 0):

this it isn't very efficient at all, but if all else fails, you could try making two procedure calls from the application one to get the invoice address and then another one to get the delivery address.

Comment: I not completely sure that I understand your suggestion - mainly because, due to the stored procedure limitation, I haven't been using LINQ at all - but I'm going to create a proof of concept project and try again.

Comment: your are having problems mapping the result set that returns both an invoice address and a delivery address.  My suggestion is to make two database calls, one will return the invoice address and the other database call will return the delivery address.